# Rearranging HEX string in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this Blob person_profile ID that looks like this.

```
5FAABE4197CBA344A6C0735C33866BF6
```

I got that output using this query

```
SELECT HEX(person_profile_id) FROM person_profile
```

Now I need a query that rearranges it so that it will look like this

```
5FAABE41-97CB-A344-A6C0-735C33866BF6
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTRING` lets your pull out parts of your hex string, while `CONCAT` allows you to put it back together, with some dashes thrown in.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
SUBSTRING(HEX(person_profile_id),1,8), '-', SUBSTRING(HEX(person_profile_id),9,4), '-', 
SUBSTRING(HEX(person_profile_id),13,4), '-', 
SUBSTRING(HEX(person_profile_id),17,4), '-', 
SUBSTRING(HEX(person_profile_id),21)
) AS id_with_dashes;
```

Comment: will this work with sqlite?

Comment: @margercastigador why did you tag MySql?

Comment: I doubt it, but I don't know. I've never used sqlite. This question was tagged MySQL when I answered it.